# How to get total number of authenticated web hits?

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

I am using Google Analytic API in java to get Google data for one of the website where my Google account is registered. I am able to get total number of hits between two specific dates, But I want to retrieve total number of authenticated web hits. I am not getting any proper way to get this data using Google Analytic.

The function that I have written for getting for number of hits is:

```
private static GaData getWebHitsByMonth(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException
{

    return analytics.data().ga().get(profileId, "2013-07-01", currentDate, "ga:hits")
          .setDimensions("ga:yearMonth")
          .execute();
}
```

Can someone give me an idea about this?

Comment: Please add code that you have tried with your question

Comment: What do you mean by authenticated hits? How are you determining/tracking who is authenticated?

Comment: @PhilipWalton hits by authenticated users...means the total number of hits by registered user (I guess).. requirement says so..

Comment: How are you letting Google Analytics know that a particular hit is coming form an authenticated user? (Or are you even doing that?)

Comment: I don't know..I want to ask whether we can do it using GA or not? If not what is the other way?

Comment: Yes, it can be done, I just wanted to make sure you weren't already doing something before answering.

Comment: Yeah... I don't know the way...dat's why I didn't start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Google Analytics has no way of knowing whether or not a user is authenticated, you have to tell it. There are two ways to approach sending this information to Google Analytics: the first (easier) is with a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?), and the second (more involved, but more useful) is by using the [User ID](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662) feature.

If you go the route of using a custom dimension, you'll basically just have to set that on your tracker object as soon as you know that a user is logged in. Assuming this is the first custom dimension you've made, the code might look like this.

```
// Set that the user is logged in.
ga('set', 'dimension1', true);
```

Now all subsequent hits sent to GA will include this value. (Note: you'll want to set it to `false` if the user logs out.)

To report on that data, you can use a filter to limit the returned results to only authenticated hits. It might look something like this: `filter=ga:dimension1==true`.

The second option is to use the User ID feature. The User ID is another dimension, and it allows you to track logged in users across multiple devices.

The main catch with using User ID is you are not allowed to send any personally identifiable information (PII), so it may require a bit more development work to create the User ID; however, if you're able to do that, it's probably the better route to go.

Here are some developer guides to help get you started with the implementation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Thanks @PhilipWalton for solution with wondeful explanation :)